# Component ID form:composite:j_id2 has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf-2, duplicates, composite-component

`/test.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">
    <f:view>

        <h:head>
            <title>Default Title</title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <h:form id="form">
                <composite:test id="composite"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>

    </f:view>

</html>
```

`/resources/components/test.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <head>
        <title>(For validation only)</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>

        <p:panel header="header foo bar">

            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="foo"/>

                    <h:outputText value="bar"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:panel>

        </p:panel>

    </cc:implementation>

</body>

</html>
```

This combination gives:

```
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID form:composite:j_id2 has already been found in the view.
```

with this tree:

```
GRAVE: JSF1007: Duplicate component ID form:composite:j_id2 found in view.
GRAVE: +id: j_id1
 type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@47080ae5
  +id: javax_faces_location_HEAD
   type: com.sun.faces.component.ComponentResourceContainer@2daf59b3
    +id: j_id3
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@532a0e33
    +id: j_id4
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@6e0a60ec
    +id: j_id5
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@6b615e64
    +id: j_id6
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@457c2e4f
    +id: j_id7
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@5bc4682c
    +id: j_id8
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@3b934fc5
  +id: j_idt37
   type: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  +id: j_idt38
   type: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  +id: j_idt39
   type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@610364d1
    +id: j_idt40
     type: 
            <title>Default Title</title>

  +id: j_idt55
   type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@25d00719
    +id: form
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@7c820db3
      +id: composite
       type: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer@3e51a2a1
        +id: j_id2
         type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@445a2d11
          +id: j_idt52
           type: org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel@618c17fd
            +id: j_idt53
             type: org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel@347b1513
              +id: j_id2
               type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@7c44da25
                +id: j_idt50
                 type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@7ca4ad4f
                +id: j_idt54
                 type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1f6e5d77
  +id: j_idt47
   type: 
</html>
```

However, if I change composite component this way:

`/resources/components/test.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <head>
        <title>(For validation only)</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>

        <p:panel header="header foo bar">

            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="foo"/>

                        <h:outputText value="bar"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </p:panel>

        </p:panel>

    </cc:implementation>

</body>

</html>
```

Adding a `<h:panelGroup>` in `<f:facet>` solves the problem.
Bad tree indexing or am I missing something? I'm using mojarra 2.1.3 and PrimeFaces 3.0.M4-SNAPSHOT under Glassfish 3.1.1.

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue right now and so would really appreciate some related information on what exactly is causing the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to JSF2 documentations, The `<f:facet>` tag can have only one child. If you have many elements which you want to nest inside a facet tag, you should first wrap them in some other container like `<h:panelGroup>`, then put that single parent container in the `<f:facet>`.

exactly what you have done!

### Here is the reference:

**[JavaServer Faces 2.0, The Complete Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071625097) - Authors: Ed Burns, Chris Schalk**

(ISBN-10: 0071625097 | ISBN-13: 978-0071625098)

Page Number: 538

Abstract:

> The **f:facet** tag signifies a nested component that has a special
>   relationship to its enclosing tags. For example, stating that the
>   "header" of a table is to be provided by a JSF component. This element
>   adds the component represented by the JSF action in its body as a
>   facet with the specified name to the component represented by the
>   closest JSF component parent action element. This tag only allows one
>   component to be nested whithin itself. *To use multiple component as a
>   facet, create them as children of a simple container component. For
>   example, nest the corresponding HTML library component actions within
>   the body a **panelGroup** component.*

Comment: i don't know what kind of documentation you have, but i couldn't find this thing anywhere. hope it's not "Marashi 2.0"...

Comment: @animanera You are right it is not in oracle official references! but anyway I mentioned my resource ;) It was not Marashi 2.0 :D

Answer (score 0):

Regarding error JSF1007 please check out this : [artilce](http://my-java-planet.blogspot.com/2013/09/jsf-errors-jsf1007-duplicate-component.html)

Comment: Elementary my dear Watson. What's the added value for such a answer?